# Does JSON.stringify increases length of the string?

Tags: javascript, json

I am facing a peculiar problem. For my REST API, I need to validate that mobile number is 10 digits. But when I do JSON.stringify it is showing length as 12.

```
var num = req.body.phone;
    console.log(num);
console.log((JSON.stringify(num)).length);
    console.log((JSON.stringify(num)).length==10);
```

Output:

```
1111111111
12
10
```

Comment: What is `typeof num`?

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `JSON.stringify` to convert a number to a string. Just append a empty string instead:

```
var num = 1234,
    str = num + '';
console.log(str, str.length); // "1234", 4
```

Or, if you prefer, use `.toString()`:

```
var num = 1234,
    str = num.toString();
console.log(str, str.length); // "1234", 4
```

Or:

```
var str = String(1234);
console.log(str, str.length); // "1234", 4
```

---

To answer the question in your title:
`JSON.stringify` does **not** add any special characters when called on a number. It just converts the number to a string:

```
var str = JSON.stringify(1234);
console.log(str, str.length); // "1234", 4
```

You probably have some extra characters in your input that you're missing. Or, most likely, the input you're `stringify`-ing **already is** a string. In that case, it adds a extra set of quotes:

```
var str = JSON.stringify("1234");
console.log(str, str.length); // ""1234"", 6
```

Comment: Or, if you prefer, just use `str = String(num)`

Comment: @Bergi: I didn't think about that one, will edit it in. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you're actually doint is to stingify a string.
In your form the inputfield contains the value as a string, not as an integer.
So if your phone-value is something like `"123"` and not `123`.

What JSON.stringify is now doing is to pack you "123" into a string `""`. The result of this is now this: `""123""`